# Can't post data to twitter from my application?

Tags: iphone, twitter

My application can post data (picture and text) to twitter a month ago. But now, it can't post data to twitter. Why..., please? Follow

> Error: [Whoa there! The request token for this page is invalid. It may
>   have already been used, or expired because it it too old. Please go
>   back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it
>   was probably jusst a mistake]

With this message, i can't confirm:
1. already been used: when it's this error?
2. expired because it it too old: the twitter has expired for token? how to re-open expired?
=> What's solution for this error? Thanks!

Comment: I found at solution http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1537. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on ios 5 then following code will be helpful as I send image and text with help of this code.

first of all add framework "twitter.framework"

```
NSString *var = txtTwitter.text;
    NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"INDEX"];


    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    // Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    // Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) {
            // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];


            if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {

                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

                TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"] parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

                //add text
                [postRequest addMultiPartData:[var dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] withName:@"status" type:@"multipart/form-data"];

                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"00%@.jpg",str]];

                //add image
                [postRequest addMultiPartData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) withName:@"media" type:@"multipart/form-data"];

                // Set the account used to post the tweet.
                [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                    NSLog(@"Twitter msg %@",output);
                    //                        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayText:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Thanks! I must use MGTwitterEngine because my application's woking on iOS 4, 5

Answer (score 0):

The error might be because your request token has got expired.
You need to regenerate your access token.

Go to https://dev.twitter.com/ and Click on recreate access token.

Comment: Thanks! But this solution then i must compile my app again because this parameter include in app's code.

Comment: Yes, you need to compile your app again.Since these tokens are very confidential , twitter expires token in some period of time.

Comment: How to development a bussiness app for apple market if twitter expires token in some period of time? How long to twitter token expires?

Comment: As you said,since you have not used those tokens for a month ,due to that that has expired,else the token will work fine.